# Windows phone 8 view / edit user custom dictionary

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is it possible to programmatically view or edit the user's custom autocorrect dictionary on windows phone 8?

I'd like to allow the user to add and remove words from their custom dictionary, but I have been unsuccessful in determining if the api provides access to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible in WP to programmatically access custom dictionary to read/write words.
However, there is a way to clear all suggestions at once, you can find that option in Settings -> Keyboard.

But again, no programmatic access.

You will more detail on this topic here:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wptips/how-to-view-or-edit-the-custom-dictionary/c998a544-9981-4848-b2c4-4b814d53b573